# Converting ASCII characters to Unicode characters

Tags: python, unicode, transliteration

I know that one can convert the Unicode characters to ASCII characters using the unidecode module in Python (https://github.com/iki/unidecode). Is there any module or a tool that would help me convert the ASCII characters to Unicode of the mentioned language, or should one code it considering the transliteration rules of the language?

The sample input and expected output is as follows:

input:
bre

output:
ಬರೆ

Comment: Any Ascii character is a Unicode character, so the question lacks a clear problem statement, in addition to asking for a favorite tool (which is classified as off-topic).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: What I mean to say is, that I want to reverse transliterate a romanized text(ASCII) of a language to the native script (Unicode) of the native language, as mentioned in the example.

Comment: if you mean that, you should say it in the question itself and also specify which of the zillions of transliteration schemes you would wish to apply. But even then, it would be asking for a favorite tool.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to rely on a separate module.  Unicode doesn't touch on this sort of functionality at all.

The [transliterate module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/transliterate) seems current and has reasonable documentation.